# Angular: Service not working in component

Tags: html, angular

I am working on an Angular app where I am using the following structure:

- app

  - layouts

    - admin-layout // I have declared my service here
  - pages

    - dashboard
    - icons
    - table
    - user
  - shared // here I have two components footer and navbar
  - sidebar

I want to access my service that I have declared in admin-layout in one of shared component's, that is navbar. I want to disable the search button until the user logs in. However, somehow the service doesn't update the value of the variable that I am trying to import. If the user has logged in the service should return the variable as true. But, it doesn't. It stays the same in my component. One more thing, the navbar component DOESN'T HAVE ANY ROUTE/PATH. I don't know if service can be accessed inside such a component. Here's my code:

> navbar.component.ts

```
allowSearch: boolean = false;

constructor(private authService: AuthService, location:Location, private renderer : Renderer2, 
private element : ElementRef, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient)

  buttonEnable()
  {
    console.log(this.allowSearch);

    if(this.authService.isAuthenticated()) //after the user logs in this should get executed
    {
      this.allowSearch = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
      console.log(this.allowSearch);

    }
  }
```

> navbar.component.html

```
 <form>
    <div class="input-group no-border">
      <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."            
      (change) = "buttonEnable()" [(ngModel)] = "searchElement" name = "searchElement"
        style = "background-color: #faf9f9" id = "searchElement" >
      <div class="input-group-append" style = "background-color: #faf9f9">
        <button  type="button" name="button" type = "submit" [disabled] = "!allowSearch" (click) = 
        "openModal2(); onSearch(searchElement)"><i class="nc-icon nc-zoom-split"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?
EDIT:

> navbar.module.ts

```
  import { AuthService } from "../../layouts/admin-layout/auth.service";

  @NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule, CommonModule, NgbModule, HttpClientModule, 
  FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ NavbarComponent ],
  exports: [ NavbarComponent ],
  providers: [AuthService]
  })
```

> auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService
{
  loggedIn:boolean = false;

  check_Authentication(logIn : boolean)
  {
   if(logIn == true)
   {
    this.loggedIn = true;
   }
   else
  {
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }
  }

 isAuthenticated()
{
  if(this.loggedIn == true)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
 }
}

 isNotAuthenticated()
{
 if(this.loggedIn != true)
 {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
   return false;
 }
 }

 }
```

Comment: can we share what your app.module.ts looks like

Comment: @Roj, Yes, I have updated my question.

Comment: Share your authService code and tell us how userLoggedIn variable is getting updated in that.

Comment: @VimalPatel, I have updated the question.

Comment: are you using `injectable` decorator on your Service?

Comment: @Roj, yes, I am using injectable in my auth-guard.service.ts. However, I am not using any injectable in my auth.service.ts, where I check for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. I was adding AuthService in providers array in navbar.module.ts. This was creating separate instances of auth.service.ts. I wanted one instance of that. So, I emptied the providers array in my navbar.module.ts and only added the AuthService in providers array in app.module.ts.

Comment: next time in your `injectable` decorator just pass `providedIn` and assign `root` like so`@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})`

Comment: so you dont have to add to your `app.module,ts` not sure why the new version of angular adds services to providers when generated